# How to get href attribute using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<table class="table1">
    <tbody>        
       <tr class="tablerow1"> 
            <td valign="top"> 
              <strong> 
              <a href="http://www.wineweb.com/scripts/wineryPg.cfm/11094/Aan-de-Doorns-Co%2Dop/" target="_top">Aan de Doorns Co-op </a> </strong> </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It's a sample html there are multiple rows with multiple cells in actuall html that's how i am doing

```
$('table.table1').each(function(k, elem) {
                    $(this).find('tr').each(function(j, elem){
                        $(this).find('td').each(function(i,elem){
                            console.log($(this).find('strong a').attr('href'));
                        })
                    })
                });
```

but I am unable to get href through this method.

Comment: was going to ask for html but it was just put up.  I suggest putting this into one query.

Comment: it seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/wCAWT/

Comment: Your code works fine as it on Waterfox. `$('table.table1').each(function(){console.log($(this).find('tr>td>strong>a').attr('href'));});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code dramatically:

```
$('table.table1 tr td a').each(function(idx, elem) {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: I know, i know. I'd like to being reminded of those parameters as quite often I make use of them later on ;).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `map` method and avoid nested `$.each` statements.

```
    var hrefs = $('table.table1 tr td a').map(function() {
        return this.href;
    }).get();

   console.log(hrefs.join(','))
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UBdBk/)**

Comment: What are you using `.get();` for?

Comment: Map return a Array encased inside a jQuery wrapper. To convert that into a normal array we use `get().`

Comment: I tried it out in your fiddle. It seems to have the exact same outcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.table1 strong a').each(function() {
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` -> `this.href`

Comment: '.table1 strong a', just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the find method (is more efficient).

```
$('.table1').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class to the a tag like this:

```
<a class="link" href="your_url" target="_top">Aan de Doorns Co-op </a>
```

then use the class in your jquery snippet like this:

```
console.log($(this).find('.link').attr('href'));
```

i've created a fiddle for this..hope it helps

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyrjj/)